# How delete temporary files?

Tags: java, file, jsp, jsf, jboss

I saved a few *.pdf* files in a folder specified in jboss.

Now what I want is to remove those files after the user ends the session in the application.

Answer (score 4):

Simply register [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) and delete the temporary file when session is destroyed in the same way you saved them.

Just keep the absolute path of the created file/folder somewhere in the session and delete the complete folder/files on session destroy.

#### web.xml:

```
<web-app ...>
    <listener>
          <listener-class>com.x.y.z.MySessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

#### HttpSessionListener:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("sessionCreated");
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("sessionDestroyed");
        // delete the file in the same way you have saved it there

        // String absolutePath = (String) e.getSession().getAttribute("pdfPath");
        // File file = new File(absolutePath);
        // if(file.exists()){ file.delete(); } 
    }
}
```

Please have a look at [Java – Delete Folder and Files](http://omtlab.com/java-delete-folder-and-files/)

Comment: You're welcome. Don;t forget to close the thread if issue is resolved.